# Improving the icons in css

Tags: css, sass, font-awesome

[image]

I'm learning css(scss) and i've problem with stylistic my text.
How i can get text in one line and how to center icon from fontawsome to the text?

```
main {
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0.6;

  .icons {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 3rem;
    opacity: 1;

    .fire {
      color: red;
      display: flex;
      padding-top: 5%;
      padding-left: 3%;
      position: absolute;
      margin-top: 10%;

      p {
        padding-left: 5%;
        display: flex;
        color: blanchedalmond;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There are not enough information. Can you also provide the html code snippet?

Comment: try using `white-space: nowrap` if you haven't for the text

Comment: Yes, here is full html and css. 
https://codepen.io/elexsccn/pen/GRZbgQv


I tried no-wrap but to no avail